# How can I save an empty model (I only need it's pk created)

Tags: python, django, models

I have these models:

```
class Storage(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.id)

class StorageType(models.Model):
    tripa = 'Tripa'
    portada = 'Portada'
    type_choice = (
        (tripa, 'Tripa'),
        (portada, 'Portada'),
    )
    sto_type = models.CharField(max_length=9, choices=type_choice, default=tripa)
    storage = models.ForeignKey(Storage)
    paper_type = models.ForeignKey(Paper)
    paper_qnty = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0)
    web_paper_qnty = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s of %s' %(self.sto_type, str(self.storage))
```

And I need to make a form (inline form?) to create a new "Storage" that holds 2 "StorageType", but I don't know what to put in my forms.py because "Autofield" is not represented in the form.

Comment: You do realize that the `id` field, as specified on your `Storage` model is completely redundant, right?

Comment: Ok, can you explain what is the problem you are trying to solve ? Looks like you can completely do away with the storage model if the only field in that is the id field.

Comment: @Brandon, i know it is redundant, but django gave me a weird error because i cant make an empty model.

Comment: @karthikr I want to retrieve only the 2 StorageType that are in the Storage model. Something like:

Select * FROM StorageType WHERE Storage = 'x'

Comment: @RogerGonzalez You can make an empty model by just supplying a docstring comment as to what the model is for, but I'm not seeing the point.

Comment: try stor = Storage(); stor.save();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Storage" that holds 2 "StorageType"

That means `Storage` can have many `StorageType` and `StorageType` can have Storages. Make a new ManyToMany Field in the storage.

```
class Storage(models.Model):
    storage_types = models.ManyToManyField(StorageType)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.id)

class StorageType(models.Model):
    tripa = 'Tripa'
    portada = 'Portada'
    type_choice = (
        (tripa, 'Tripa'),
        (portada, 'Portada'),
    )
    sto_type = models.CharField(max_length=9, choices=type_choice, default=tripa)
    paper_type = models.ForeignKey(Paper)
    paper_qnty = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0)
    web_paper_qnty = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s of %s' %(self.sto_type, str(self.storage))
```

---

Then read [Django Many-to-many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

Comment: Yes, this is a better aproach. Thank you!